# Perl - Full Screen Scrolling

Tags: perl, paging, screen, fullscreen

Was wondering if there was a way to have output in perl via the command line be scrollable a "page at a time"; like less/more in *Nix.  I found something close in stackoverflow archives, but i don't think it will work for me.

I need to output to detect the screen size and know what "full screen" is, whether that is a small window, or truly a full-screen window, and be able to do this on small or large monitors.

Someone referenced the Perl module Term::Pager - maybe someone can assist with this.  However, nowhere did I see anything such as "auto" or something to have the output know what a true full screen was. The reason being is due to the amount of output that the program will generate (due to design), I need a "paging" feature.

**Code as of 12/4 9:45AM CST**

```
open MORE, '|more' or die "unable to start pager";
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "can't open <$file> for reading $!"; {
    local $/ = "TYPE:\n";
    while ( my $record = <$fh> ) {
        [ .. snip snip ...]
```

How would I go about doing this to another open statement?

Comment: I misunderstood the question. Apologies. Please ignore close vote.

Comment: No, this is a question about Perl.  I want the program to do this, not the OS command line - I'm not piping any commands to it; I'm running it and having the perl app do the paging.

Comment: Will do :) thanks for updating your comment.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "doing this to another open statement".  How you're getting your input has nothing to do with how you're printing your output.  You only need to open a pager once, then just keep printing to it.

Answer (score 2):

just pipe the output to *less* or *more*:

```
open MORE, '|more' or die "unable to start pager";
print MORE "hello $_!\n" for 1..1000;
```

Comment: I updated my question.  I verified that this works, however, in my environment, it won't work, but maybe you would know how to fix when nesting open statements.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -CLA
use 5.010;
use utf8;
use strict;
use autodie;
use warnings qw< FATAL all >;
use open qw< IO :utf8 :std>;
use sigtrap qw< stack-trace normal-signals error-signals >;
END { close STDOUT }

if (-t STDOUT) {
    my $pager = $ENV{PAGER} || "less";
    open(STDOUT, "| $pager");
}
```

If you prefer to be infernally annoying like Python or Java:

```
use Carp;
$^W = 1;
local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { confess "untrapped warning" };
```

That should win you friends in certain postmodernist snob-circles, but whether you value their esteem  is not for me to say.

Comment: Not sure if you read my update to the original question - I'm needing to "page" output, but it's reading from a file, so I need to know how to handle this.

Comment: I've seen you paste code like this before.  I'm not asking for you to rewrite my code.  If you want to give me ideas or code samples, please adhere to my current code; this makes it so confusing when you include a bunch of other stuff.  I need to just know how to page everything that is in a while loop; reread my whole question.  Your solution doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Drew: I did just as you asked. Why are you saying otherwise? What part of I/O do not understand? Do you not know how to read a line, or do you not know how to write a line? Since you only mentioned paging output, I presume you have got the input side taken care. So tell me precisely what part of `print` side of the equation that is confusing you?  If I have to put in every single bit of I/O, then you **ARE** demanding that I rewrite your code for it. Frankly, if you cannot handle one `print` statement, no amount of help will do more than hurt you.

Comment: I'm still looking into this and I'll get back to this soon.